# Change button image on mouse over during drag and drop operation

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, button, drag-and-drop

I have a listview with some items. Also I have two buttons, add and delete. I have implemented drag and drop functionality in order to drag a single listviewitem from listview to the delete button and then on delete button drop, delete the listview item.

When listview item is dragged from listview to delete button and mouse is over the button (during drap and drop operation and before drop on button) I want to change the button image. It is working if I create a data trigger on button on IsMouseOver property, but I only want to change the button image when mouse is over the delete button during drag and drop operation (before drop).  How can I do this?

```
<Button  AllowDrop="True" Drop="btnDrop_Drop" Height="64" Width="64" Margin="10" Click="Button_Click_Delete" Content="Delete">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="image1" Visibility="Visible" Height="36" Width="36" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Resources/icons8-Trash Can-48.png"/>
                <Image x:Name="image2" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="36" Width="36" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Resources/icons8-Trash Can-48-3.png"/>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Delete</Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="image1" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter TargetName="image2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use EventTriggers to handle the [Drop Target Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview).

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="image1" Opacity="1" ... />
        <Image x:Name="image2" Opacity="0" ... />
        ...
    </StackPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Storyboard x:Key="swapImages" TargetProperty="Opacity">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image1" To="0" Duration="0" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image2" To="1" Duration="0"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="resetImages" TargetProperty="Opacity">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image1" To="1" Duration="0" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image2" To="0" Duration="0"/>
        </Storyboard>

    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragOver">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource swapImages}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource resetImages}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Drop">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource resetImages}"/>
        </EventTrigger>

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

- adressing `Opacity` instead of `Visibility`.
- when defining `Storyboard`s in `Resources`, their location in the xaml file is important. `Resources` should be defined first (before the `Triggers` using them) or initialization will fail.

Comment: Your solution works partially. I mean, icons are swapping correctly but as you are using opacity and not visibility property this cause the following problems: label under my button is not visible because then using opacity the image wih the opacity set to 0 is occuping space despite not being visible, so total height of image1+image2+label is bigger than my button height 64. Second problem is: on mouse over button, it toggle the new icon, but this icon is not placed at the same position of the old one, instead it is placed under image1.

Comment: Maybe it is needed to swap image localtion as well when swapping images or some kind of equivalent imagelist in winforms and select the image to be visible. How to do it?

Comment: @user1624552 Added a `Style` to `Resources` to address these issues.